Sidebar exit or collapsing
Well I am here in situation where on a button inside toolbar user would open this sidebar with some filters and it has tabs on the top,filters below it etc. Now problem is how to create some way of closing sidebar (one way would be to close it from same button from which is opened) but I need second way as well...I was thinking of just putting X on the top but it looks really weird with Tabs below. Anyone has some suggestion of doing it ?

You can put a CTA on the bottom of the sidebar. I have had experiences where making a sidebar closeable by just clicking outside of it confuses users, and they aren't sure if the action they have done will be saved.
I've added 2 examples

The main action is done inside of the sidebar (selecting items) and pressing return. (i have chosen not to name it save, as the actions are saved by clicking the checkbox)

The main action comes from the sidebar





If I understood your problem correctly, you can use one of the following icons for closing the side bar.


I did think about using that, but I use that exact icon in toolbar for opening other sidebar. (It's pretty complex software like SAP. so it has milion of options)

Interesting problem... But don't you think as user's mental modal is already built for opening/closing the sidebar by using this icon, it can help user to make the decision faster. That way you can also maintain the consistency for opening/closing sidebar too.
